# Adding Integer from textbox to database c#

Tags: c#, database

I'm a newbie to c# and am having some difficulty getting an integer from a textbox to a database.

I have created a simple form which allows a user to input their firstName, lastName, and age.

I can connect the firstName and lastName to the database on a buttonClick, but am unable to to the same with age. Here is what I have.

```
   private void AddTheNewInfoToDB()
    {
        using (DatabaseContainer db = new DatabaseContainer())
        {
            Users u = new Users();

            u.firstName = textboxfirstName.Text;
            u.lastName = textboxlastName.Text;
            u.Age = textboxAge.Text; 


            db.Users.AddObject(u);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

When I do this, I get an error for the "textboxAge.Text" which says "Cannot implicitly convert tye 'string' to 'int'."

Advice on fixing this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
u.Age = Int32.Parse(txtboxAge.Text);
```

You're having a problem, because were trying to assign a string (.Text) to a variable of type Int (Age).

Comment: This will work but keep in mind that `textboxAge.Text` may not be constrained to just numbers. If it contains invalid characters it will throw a `FormatException`

Comment: @Nathan, sure, but one should apply validation logic 24/7. If he does, there's no need to apply additional checks in db access layer to verify the data again.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
int age;
int.TryParse(textboxAge.Text, out age); 
u.Age = age;
```

Comment: This is wrong. It should be `int.TryParse(textboxAge.Text, out age);` and it wont set `age` to 0 `age` will remain as it was, point of fact 0.

Comment: You consider a good habit to repair a bad input? Because that's exactly what you're doing. If the user provides a bad input (e.g. a string), you should notify him and NOT allow him to post to db. But instead, you've decided it's valid for someone to have age = 0 and actually update the db?

Comment: @walther: you do your validation together with the actual database operation? I'd imagine the validation should be done BEFORE the post to db actually takes place. Also, regardless of the validation trifle, `TryParse` is still the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: @Nathan: I invite you to review this in `Reflector`. I'm sure you'll realize that what you just said is in fact, untrue. The `TryParse` will set the out variable to 0 before reporting a boolean result.

Comment: @code4life, precisely, validation should be done BEFORE. That means when you're doing the insert/update, you already know it contains an integer within a specified range = you don't have to tryparse, simple parse will do. Why do you consider it superior to parse in this particular case?

Comment: @walther: it's significantly faster and doesn't throw exceptions. Check the `Reflector` and you will see what I mean.

Comment: @code4life Interesting, thanks for pointing that out. I wonder why that's not mentioned on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)

Comment: @code4life, thanks for the explanation, I'll definitely check that out.

Answer (score 0):

use `int.parse(textboxAge.Text);`